# Method to find the set S of reals $λ$ such as $rg($M-I3)<3 given a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, gaussian-elimination

Considering the endomorphism $f$ of $R^3$ of

\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 5 & -5\\ 
-4 & 6 & -5\\ 
 -4& 4 &-3 
\end{bmatrix}

relatively of the canonical base bc of $R^3$
find  the set S of reals $λ$ such as $rg($M-$λ$I3)<3

What method should I use? I tried the Gaussian elimination but it becomes awkward and difficult at some point. Can you give some details?

Comment: Where does λ play  a role?

Comment: Sorry, a typo! In rg(M-λI)

Comment: Use Sarrus's rule to compute the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Does rg denote the rank?

Comment: Per Bernard's suggestion, the usual approach is to calculate $\det(M - \lambda I_3)$ as a function of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rg means rank, you know that $rg(M-\lambda I_3)\leq 3$. Find the set A of $\lambda$'s for which the rank is 3 (think about when is the rank of a matrix equal to its dimension) and the answer will be $S=\mathbb{R}-A$.